# Type declaration in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I just started learning Haskell.  I decided to set myself a goal of implementing an old algorithm of mine http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.79.7006&rep=rep1&type=pdf

As a start I wrote the following code

```
phi [] = [1..]
phi (p:pl) = (phi pl) `minus` (map (p*) $ phi pl)
primes x
       | x < 2 = []
       | otherwise = smallprimes ++ (takeWhile (<=x) $tail $ phi $ reverse smallprimes)
     where  smallprimes = primes $ sqrt x

minus (x:xs) (y:ys) = case (compare x y) of
         LT -> x  :    minus xs (y:ys)
         EQ ->         minus xs    ys
         GT ->         minus (x:xs) ys
minus xs        _   = xs
```

This functions as expected, except that the list of primes comes as floating point!  A little thought told me that since the signature of sqrt is

```
sqrt :: (Floating a) => a -> a
```

the Haskell compiler has decided that primes is returning a list of floats.
However, when I tried to tell it that

```
phi :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
```

which is what I want, the compiler has a problem:

```
No instance for (Floating Integer)
  arising from a use of `sqrt` at ...
```

So how do I signify the phi takes as input a list of integers and as output produces an infinite list of Integers?

Comment: Try combining `sqrt` with other functions, like `fromIntegral` and `floor`, to get a square root function of the right type.

Comment: The code given doesn't seem to work--I'm guessing it's just transcription errors formatting it for SO, since you said it worked otherwise, but `(tail phi $ reverse smallprimes)` doesn't seem to make sense, nor does the `LT` case in `minus`.

Comment: Sorry, I made a transcription error.  Try it now.  I just realied if I changed the (<=x) in the argument of takeWhile to (<= (floor x)) that it now works ok.

Comment: As it stands and assuming a `$` between `tail`and `phi` this is indeed a strange thing. Even if the argumet to `primes` is floating point, there is no way this argument carries over to `phi`.
So I have doubts the code is really the one you compiled?

Comment: Yep -- usually one or two well placed conversion functions are all you need -- the trick is where :-) Thanks for the link to the paper also -- looks interesting, and lazy recursive sieving type algorithms are extremely nice in Haskell.

Comment: @sclv Yep now I know.  I believe that the compiler's reasoning goes something like this: it sees that there is a call prime $ sqrt x so, since sqrt returns a Floating value, that prime must take a Floating argument.  Then it looks at takeWhile (<=x) and sees that since x is Floating that the second argument to takeWhile must be [Floating].  Since it comes from phi (via tail) it then assumes that phi produces something of type [Floating].

Comment: continuation:  And finally since phi is called with phi $ reverse primelist it assumes that phi's signature is [Floating] -> [Floating].  Is there an option in the Haskell compiler to spell out that reasoning?  If so, it would have helped me a lot!

Comment: Generally the type inference engine is too complicated to ask for that sort of thing. What you *can* do is annotate values with what you think they should be, which helps to narrow things down pretty rapidly.

Answer (score 6):

The problem in your code is, that `sqrt` expects a floating point number and returns the same. You have to use a wrapper that converts the type to make it work. (That's essentially, what the error message says):

```
smallprimes = primes . ceiling . sqrt . fromIntegral $ x
```

Haskell has no automatic conversion between different numeric types, as this is not possible with the type system Haskell has.

Comment: interested in getting the link to the Haskell-Wiki in there? I think it puts value to the answer and I can delete my almost redundant answer this way ... ?

Comment: Thanks.  It fromIntegral that I was missing.  But I'd really like to allow an argument of primes to be a real (i.e. Floating) since that's a typical thing to do in Number Theory.  I tried changing (x < 2) to ((ceiling x) < 2) thinking that that might do it, but I still get floating point answers.

Comment: It's true there's no automatic conversion between _all_ numeric types, but in practice you can achieve the effect on a few types. You can define a multi-parameter type class, which can run all of the desired operations (+), (-), etc. on numbers of different types. (This was in some classic paper, maybe on associated types? I forget, sorry.)

Answer (score 2):

take a look at that: [Converting numbers](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers#Converting_to_Integral)

`ceiling` should too the trick (as FUZxxl pointed out allready)

IMHO the difficult part here is that the languages we are used to cast types by pointing to your target - Haskell switches the logic in a mind-bending way here ...

Comment: Actually I tried floor i.e. I wrote, i.e. I wrote (floor sqrt x) instead of sqrt x but that didn't work either -- Haskell refused to compile it.

Comment: Well actually floor is right, since I meant primes x to return { p prime : p <= x}

Comment: @VictorMiller: I'm not sure if it will fit with your algorithm, but a common trick is to stick with integers and just square `p` instead of taking the square root of `x`.

Comment: @Victor Miller: If you wrote `floor sqrt x` literally then the error you probably got was because this parses as `(floor sqrt) x`. Whitespace-separated identifiers are left-associative function application with higher precedence than anything other than built-in syntax.

Comment: @C.A.McCann : I actually wrote floor $ sqrt x .

Comment: Oh, and note that following @hammar's suggestion about squared values instead of square roots not only avoids conversions, it avoids loss of precision--`Integer` is an arbitrary-sized integer type, whereas floating point types are the usual limited-precision deal. In this particular case, though, I suppose you probably won't be exceeding the range of values that `Double` can express exactly...